# C - gathering the sum/average from for loop

Tags: c

I'm having a hard time understanding how to grab the numbers I want,

```
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
```

I see that the number is adding 1 each time until it reaches the input of i, however, let's say I wanted to get the sum or average of these numbers. How would I pull each number and add them since the int r will be changed to the next rand integer each time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAXN 1000
#define MIN 0

int main(void) {
    int n, r, i;
    int pos = 0;
    int minpos = 0;
    int max, min;
    int num[MAXN];
    float sum = 0.0, average;

    printf("Enter an integer");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    srand(time(0));

printf("\n Pos | Val"); //setting up Pos/Val table
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    r = (int)(((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 1000) + 1;
    printf("\n %3d | %3d", i + 1, r);
    num[i] = r;
}
printf("\n");

max = num[0]; //finding the maximum number
i = 1;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (num[i] > max)
    {
        max = num[i];
        pos = i;
    }
}

min = num[0]; //finding the minimum number
i = 1;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (num[i] < min)
    {
        min = num[i];
        minpos = i;
    }
}

printf("\nMax : %d | Pos : %d", max, pos + 1); //biggest number
//while (1);
printf("\nMin : %d | Pos : %d", min, minpos + 1); //smallest number
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer 5

 Pos | Val
   1 | 493
   2 | 774
   3 |  62
   4 | 896
   5 | 183

Max : 896 | Pos : 4
Min : 62 | Pos : 3
```

Comment: You neednt additional array for finding min/max. You can check it in first loop.

Comment: If you sort the list then, depending on how you sort, the min will be the first element and max will be the last. This can be a lot faster than running two linear searches. You should research insertion sort.

Comment: As for summing the random numbers, do that when generating them by simply adding the line `sum += r;` to the end of your first for loop.

Comment: How would I check it in the first loop @FilipKočica

Comment: and I will look into that aswell @JonnyHenley

Comment: @MichaelJohnson You are generating values in interval <0,1000> right ? Or maybe not, it doesnt matter, just before loop set max to minimal generated value, in this case 0, and min to maximal genereted value, in this case 1000. In loop that check if genereted value is bigger/less than min/max.

Comment: @FilipKočica OP is generating numbers in the range [0...1001] with `r = (int)(((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 1000) + 1;`  It is a poor way to generate such numbers, not a uniform distribution.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before each closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the first of these two lines is redundant: `i = 1;  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)`

Comment: this code block: `for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            pos = i;
        }` is setting `pos` to `n`  so why all the convolution.  just use: `i = n;`

Comment: this statement: `max = num[0]; //finding the maximum number` appears twice in the same area of code.  Which one do you actually want to use?

Comment: this statement: `float sum = 0.0` is trying to set a `float` variable from a `double` literal.  While implicit conversion will probably save you, much better to write: `float sum = 0.0f`

Comment: when calling `scanf()` to input the value for `n`, there is absolutely nothing stopping the user from entering a value greater than 999.so the code should be testing that value to assure that it is >0 and <1000  AND should be checking the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `srand(time(0));` 1) a parameter to `time()` needs to be a pointer, if used at all. 0 is not a pointer, although implicit conversion may save you. 2) the function: `srand()` is expecting a `unsigned int` parameter, and `time()` returns a `time_t` value. Suggest using: `srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL ) );`

Comment: this code block: `for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
                r = (int)(((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 1000) + 1;
                printf("\n %3d | %3d", i + 1, r);
                num[i] = r;
            }` appears twice in the posted code, but only needs to be performed the first time.